# Sonar HC-SR04 analog output. Multipoint Sonar Radar

Tags: arduino, analog

Im working on replicating the work found on [Ultrasonic Radar; Multi-Point](http://wildlab.org/index.php/ultrasonic-radar-arduino/).
It bypasses the echo out on HC-SR04 and enables full analog output to Arduino ADC. The results are quite good but unlike the project described on the website, anything further than cca 20 cm is noise. 
Any ideas why?

used
4.6k ohm resistor 
2x 4.7nF capacitors

Thanks,

[image: What I get]
[image]

Comment: How long are you waiting between pulses for echos to dissipate?

Comment: From the Sketch, reading is done every 15ms. No change was done to OP code

Comment: I'd try experimenting with that to longer durations just to see. Results will vary depending on where you are. The size of the room and wall material can make a big difference to how long the sound takes to dissipate.

Comment: its large room, and tried changing the delays, no joy, still the same noise.

Comment: Then you are stuck with getting a stronger signal and reducing the sensitivity of the receiver. That and cleaning up the receiver to be less sensitive to electrical noise.