# Analog Signal HC SR04

Tags: analog, ultrasound, radar

[image][image]I am very interested in this project:

[Sonar HC-SR04 analog output. Multipoint Sonar Radar](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/305685/sonar-hc-sr04-analog-output-multipoint-sonar-radar?newreg=1e39d17942284c0fae255ab93ac4d879)

I have not much experience in electronics and don't know where I have to connect my wire on the Ultrasonic sensor, to read out the analog signal.

Many thanks in advance

Comment: Read the documentation in your own link ....it shows you where to connect it. http://wildlab.org/index.php/ultrasonic-radar-arduino/

Comment: I dont´t understand the documentation. Could you circle the "collector of transistor" on my picture?

Comment: It doesn't look like the board in the documentation and the one in your picture are equivalent...

Comment: There is no discrete transistor on your picture...

Comment: Ah okay, no I see the difference. The upper picture shows now the used sensor, correct?

Answer (score 1):

The circuit in your picture is not the same one from the link provided. That is probably the source of your confusion.

Cheers.

This is the circuit from that other post:[image]

Comment: Do you know how I have to connect the wire on my IC?

Comment: Sorry @LarsBomhoff, I can't even see any markings on the IC's in your picture, so I really can't say. Is there a particular reason you want it to be analog? Check out something like this: http://www.instructables.com/id/Simple-Arduino-and-HC-SR04-Example/